# IIS6 Web Extensions change to prohibited after iisreset or server reboot?

Tags: iis, iis-6, asp.net, extension

We run IIS6 in 64-bit mode on a 64-bit server. I'm trying to allow the .net 2.0 extension to run and prohibit the 32-bit version. See below screenshot for context:

[image]

However, after a reboot or iisreset, the 64-bit version of the extension reverts to "Prohibited" and the 32-bit version reverts to "Allowed" as seen in the screenshot.

How do I fix this?

Comment: It appears to have been some type of lag in writing to the metabase. A full server reboot fixed the issue and now they stay enabled.